# Sammy JS - object doesn't support this property or method in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, sammy.js

Sammy JS - i am getting error in IE8 browser.
object doesn't support this property or method. 
Error Details on line no:2

```
(function($) {
    var app = $.sammy(function() {
            this.get('#/index', function() {
            alert('rkl');
            });
    });

    $(function() {
            app.run()
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Any Idea to solve this?

Comment: Usually that would indicate that you're not loading the plugin, haven't loaded the plugin in the correct order relative to jQuery (you have to load jQuery first), or that there was an error in the code for the plugin that resulted in it not executing fully. Is this limited to IE8 (or at least versions of IE)? If so, check the developer tools (hit F12) for errors when the page loads. Including all of your `<script>` tags to load jQuery and plugins in the question would help too.

Comment: sammy.js needs to load first or jquery needs to load first? ............. now i am loading jquery loaded first.

Comment: Sammy JS looks to be a jQuery plugin, which is essentially an extension to the base jQuery functionality. You can't extend something if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: currently i loaded both files- jquery-1.11.0.js and ejs.js(sammy js). but same coding working fine in firefox, chrome and mac. but in IE browser only its not working.

Comment: Check the developer tools (hit F12 on your keyboard) for errors when the page loads then.